# What is the difference between mteval-v13a.pl and NLTK BLEU?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk, machine-translation, bleu

There is an implementation of BLEU score in Python NLTK,
 [`nltk.translate.bleu_score.corpus_bleu`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py)

But I am not sure if it is the same as the [mtevalv13a.pl script](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/generic/mteval-v13a.pl).

**What is the difference between them?**

Comment: Why don't you compare them? If you don't know both languages well enough, at least **edit your question** and provide links to both implementations. Please see the help section of the site for information on how to write great questions that get answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu when evaluating Machine Translation systems.

**In Short**

No, the BLEU in NLTK isn't the exactly the same as the `mteval-13a.perl`.

But it can get really close, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1330#issuecomment-256237324

> `nltk.translate.corpus_bleu` corresponds to `mteval-13a.pl` up to the 4th order of ngram with some floating point discrepancies

The details of the comparison and the dataset used can be downloaded from https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/blob/gh-pages/packages/models/wmt15_eval.zip or:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wmt15_eval')
```

The major differences:

[image]

---

**In Long**

There are several difference between `mteval-13a.pl` and `nltk.translate.corpus_bleu`:

- The first difference is the fact that **`mteval-13a.pl` comes with its own NIST tokenizer** while the NLTK version of BLEU is the implementation of the metric and **assumes that input is pre-tokenized**.

  - BTW, this [ongoing PR](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1779) will bridge the gap between NLTK and NIST tokenizers
- The other major difference is that `mteval-13a.pl` expects the input to be in `.sgm` format while NLTK BLEU takes in python list of lists of strings, see the [README.txt in the zipball here for more information of how to convert textfile to SGM](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/blob/gh-pages/packages/models/wmt15_eval.zip).
- `mteval-13a.pl` expects an ngram order of at least 1-4. If the minimum ngram order for the sentence/corpus is less than 4, it will return a 0 probability which is a `math.log(float('-inf'))`. To emulate this behavior, NLTK has a put an `_emulate_multibleu` flag:

  - See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py#L477
- `mteval-13a.pl` is able to generate NIST scores while NLTK doesn't have NIST score implementation (at least not yet)

  - NIST score in NLTK is [upcoming in this PR](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1779)

Other than the differences, NLTK BLEU scores packed in more features:

- to handle fringe cases that the original BLEU (Papineni, ‎2002) overlooked

  - See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1383
- Also to handle fringe cases where the largest order of Ngram is < 4, the uniform weights of the individual ngram precision will be reweighted such that the mass of the weights sums to 1.0

  - See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py#L175
- while [NIST has a smoothing method](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/generic/mteval-v13a.pl#L834) for geometric sequence smoothing, [NLTK has an equivalent object with the same smoothing method](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py#L512) and even more smoothing methods to handle sentence level BLEU from [Chen and Collin, 2014](http://www.statmt.org/wmt14/pdf/W14-3346.pdf)

Lastly to validate the features added in NLTK's version of BLEU, a regression test is added to accounts for them, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/test/unit/translate/test_bleu.py

Comment: And now it's official, there's NIST support in NLTK =)